# About a class of expectations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

Consider being given a $n-$dimensional random vector with a distribution ${\cal D}$, vectors $a \in \mathbb{R}^k$, $\{ b_i \in \mathbb{R}^n \}_{i=1}^k$ and non-linear Lipschitz functions, $f_1,f_2 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Now under what conditions can we exactly compute (or give tight bounds on)

$$ \mathbb{E} \Big [ x f_1 \Big ( \sum_{i=1}^k a_i f_2 (b_i^\top x) \Big ) \Big ] $$

as a function of the the $a$ and $b_i$ vectors ?

---

I can hardly find any examples of non-trivial $f_1$ and $f_2$ (and ${\cal D}$ being anything "reasonable" like log-concave etc.) for which this is computable!

Comment: For an exact and non-trivial example, try a standard bivariate normal distribution with the function $f(x)=\max(-x,x/2)$.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate? I am actually quite surprised that this is the $f$ you chose. I had in mind initially a very similar $f$!

Comment: Eg one part of that expectation could be http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%7Cx%2By%2F2%7CExp%5B-x%5E2-y%5E2%5D%2FPi%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%5D

Comment: Sorry! Could you kindly say some more details? Like the expression I have written above is a vector. But you are computing a scalar. Could you kindly check that? And what are your $a_i$s and the $b_i$s?

Comment: That’s part of why I said “one part”. I don’t think these are research-level questions.

Comment: This question comes from a research area! These is a very common kind of computations that turn up in understanding neural nets and being able to understand these kinds of quantities will hugely progress theory there! Such expressions being hard to analyze is so much of the bottleneck in that area!